# IIS6 - Users login and then get redirected to login page, have to reboot their PCs to break this loop, then fine

Tags: iis-6, authentication, forms-authentication

This is an odd issue.

We have forms auth for a site, and we recently adjusted the forms auth in web.config to include:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="ourCookie"
  loginUrl="~/../Default.aspx"
  protection="All"
  path="/"
  domain="ourdomain.com"/>
</authentication>
```

Then the specified machinekey validation and decryption strings.

The one above is for a sub site, hence the ~/../

The main site just has "Default.aspx"

Anyway a small number of our users are having issues where they login to the main site and get bounced back to the login page.

Our log seems to show the user successfully logging in, but it just redirects them right back to the login page.

IF they restart their PC, then they seem to be fine.

Thoughts???

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the caching directives on the Redirect are invalid?  You might want to try looking at the sequence with a web debugger like Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com)

Comment: I will try that.  However it works for 90%+ of our users, perhaps more.  So if that was the case wouldn't that happen to all users?  Also we can't seem to reproduce it ourselfs... :(